# Conformal isomorphism of $S \subset \mathbb C$ the strip $\Im z<1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ by such conformal isomorphism s.t. for $a,b> 0$ $f(z+a) = f(z)+b$. Show that $a=b$.

I have been stuck on this for awhile - I thought to differentiate, which gives a periodic function with a Fourier series representation. However, that didn't help and didn't clearly use the fact that this is an isomorphism. I also was thinking of mapping on both ends to a unit disk but wasn't sure what to do with the property given in that case. Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Not sure i get the problem - if $f$ is a conformal automorphism of $\Im z <1$ we know all such and the result follows by a simple check ($w=1-z$ sends $\Im z <1$ to $\Im z >0$ and $g(1-z)=1-f(z)$ is a conformal automorphism of the upper half plane satisfying $g(w-a)=g(w)-b$ and those are Mobius trnasforms with real coefficients etc

Comment: Sorry having a hard time following that reasoning - yes we can conjugate and try to use knowledge of conformal mappings elsewhere but care to illustrate? I got bogged down in the details

Comment: $g(w)=\frac{cw+d}{mw+n}, cn-dm \ne 0, c,d,m,n \in \mathbb R$; use $g(w-a)=g(w)-b$ (and for example take limits as $|w| \to \infty$ to conclude $m=0$ etc

Comment: Right, except how does the property translate to the conformal mappings of the upper-half plane? What conformal mapping from the strip to the upper-half plane are you using and what happens when you apply it to $z+a$?